# Image in custom control isn't loaded in UWP (WinUI3 preview 3 C++/WinRT)

Tags: xaml, uwp, c++-winrt, winui-3

I was following the [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/xaml-templated-controls-cppwinrt-winui-3) on custom controls(templated) in WinUI3, and decided to fiddle with them (I'm new to WinUI). I've been trying to build an [Image Card](https://materializecss.com/cards.html) control, but can't seem to get my image to load from the app folder.

Markup from `MainPage.xaml` (Just the control):

```
<local:BasicCard ImgSrc="Assets/woah.jpg" Title="Title here" Content="Content Here"/>
```

The style for the control by default is in `Themes/Generic.xaml`, here's the relevant markup:

```
<ImageBrush.ImageSource>
     <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path=ImgSrc, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
</ImageBrush.ImageSource>
```

Now, **it seems to work fine if I use a hyperlink for the ImgSrc property**, but I am unable to pull it off with a local image file (in the Assets folder). Also, the same thing works fine in a desktop application, but only if I use the absolute path, whereas in the UWP app, nothing works at all(other than the https link). I've placed the woah.jpg file in all the folders and tested patterns like `Themes/woah.jpg` and just `woah.jpg` and even absolute paths, nothing works. What am I doing wrong? any help would be appreciated, and please do ask for the full markup snippets if needed.

Finally, I don't know if this matters, but I am currently registering the property as a `winrt::hstring`
like so:

```cpp
Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty BasicCard::m_ImageSourceProperty =
    Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty::Register(
        L"ImgSrc",
        winrt::xaml_typename<winrt::hstring>(),
        winrt::xaml_typename<TitleBarPlease::BasicCard>(),
        NULL
    );
```

Comment: I believe you would need to access the resource in the app package using the `ms-appx` protocol, i.e. `ImgSrc="ms-appx:///Assets/woah.jpg"`. You're also going to have to make sure that the respective resources are indeed added to the app package.

Comment: Yup, I had tried the URL you suggested, but the image wasn't part of the project. Thanks for the reply. Any Idea how one could serve incoming images in this manner?  Like if a user uploaded an image, it wouldn't be part of the package, right? Hope i'm making sense

Comment: The `Uri` type supports several protocols. [URI schemes that are specific to a Windows Runtime app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.uri#uri-schemes-that-are-specific-to-a-windows-runtime-app) describes them. For dynamically added resources you can use `ms-appdata` instead of `ms-appx`.

Comment: `ms-appdata` is what I needed, thanks for the reply, really appreciate you taking time out to help noobs like me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable) was right in pointing out that the image needs to be a part of the package, weirldy not all the resources in the Assets folder are included by default, right clicking on the image, and selecting "Include in project" solved the issue(VS 2019).